# Troubles with brackets while zooming

Tags: fonts, pdf, pixelated

### When I'm zooming the compiled document, all brackets and similar figures look like on the screen. I've already installed cm-super, so I don't have troubles with the font, but, I have no an idea why the brackets look like this.

I have two files: the main and the style. 
The preamble of the main file is:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{Lections_style}
```

In the style file kinda preamble looks:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProcessOptions
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{babel,blindtext}
\RequirePackage{subfigure}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{cite}
\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{mathabx}
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{multirow}
\RequirePackage{makecell}
\RequirePackage{mathrsfs}
```

[image]

Comment: Please give us a complete example we can compile. We want to be able to copy-paste-compile to reproduce the issue. Since this will depend in part on the context in which those symbols appear, it is pretty hard to guess at the rest of your document. Off-topic: `subfigure` ought not be used as it is obsolete.

Comment: What's the point of `\ProcessOptions` when there aren't any?

Comment: @cfr Should I past here all the 60 pages? How can I send you the example, if those brackets are used throughout the whole document? 
I've just created a new document, but I haven't met the problem. I don't know, why. Obviously then, that the problem occurs only in this doucment, which contains about 60 pages.

Comment: @cfr I forgot to put off the `\ProcessOptions`.

Comment: That seems extremely unlikely. Make a copy of your document and start taking stuff out. If the problem disappears, put it back. If not, it isn't necessary. See [how to make an MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) which explains the process.

Comment: Either add a `\usepackage{everything-but-the-kitchen-sink}` or make your code minimal and _compilable_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `T1` to the font encodings else `cm-super` won't be used i.e. `\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}` - otherwise you'll get `OT1` as the default text encoding and the default Computer Modern, I think, which isn't scalable.

Since `mathabx` is causing the problem, you need to ensure that you have scalable versions of [mathabx](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathabx-type1) installed correctly.

Obviously, you should install required packages using your TeX distribution's package manager rather than by hand e.g. `tlmgr` (for TeX Live) or TeX Live Utility (for the MacTeX flavour of TeX Live) or MikTeX's package manager (for MikTeX, obviously).

### *Explanation*

By default, TeX uses Computer Modern fonts in MetaFont (`.mf`) format. These do not scale well, especially in certain PDF viewers. Similarly, `mathabx` supplies MetaFont versions of the fonts it supports.

However, *if postscript type1 versions of fonts are available*, most TeX installations will prefer them.

Installing `cm-super` and using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` ensures that scalable versions of Computer Modern are used. An alternative is `\usepackage{lmodern}` or `\usepackage{cfr-lm}` which will use Latin Modern in type1 format.

Likewise, installing [the type1 mathabx fonts](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathabx-type1) will ensure that `mathabx` uses postscript, type1 versions provided your TeX installation is configured to prefer them. (And, trust me, it is. Unless you've changed the setting which you would have had no reason to do.)

So ensuring that [mathabx-type1](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathabx-type1) and `cm-super` are installed, and that `T1` is the default text encoding for Western European languages (as opposed to `OT1`), ensures that scalable fonts are used for these purposes rather than their MetaFont equivalents.

Postscript, type1 fonts scale well in all known PDF viewers, even those which do not scale MetaFont fonts at all well. Hence, the above should solve the problem.

Comment: This didn't solve the problem(

Comment: Hmmm. I've just started a new document, and like attached the style file to that new document. The problem has got back. Something's wrong in the style file then

Comment: I've found out, that when I use `\RequirePackage{mathabx}` I get the problem.
Seems I don't need the package right now, but If I do, what should I use to rectify the "pixelating"?

Comment: Yep, how to find out if I use scalable version?

Comment: tbh, I don't understand how to do it. Also I don't understand, how it will help me to solve the problem with that `mathabx`. Might you explain again? What if I install `mathabx-type1`?

Comment: @MGMKLML See edit. I've deleted some of my comments as this system is complaining. Perhaps you could do the same?

Comment: Installing the `mathabx-type1` solved the problem. Thank you